# std::unordered_map<>::operator[] and its return type reference

Tags: c++, reference, clion, unordered-map

```
class TestingMapClass {
public:

    TestingMapClass() : anotherStr("nothing") {}

    void Load() {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> memberMap = {
                {"name", "value"}
        };

       // Do something with the unordered map...

        anotherStr = memberMap["name"]; // The address of the local variable may escape the function
    }

private:
    std::string anotherStr;
};


int main() {

    std::string testingStr;

    {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> someMap = {
                {"one", "first"}
        };

        testingStr = someMap["one"];

    }

    std::cout << testingStr << std::endl; /// Local variable 'testingStr' may point to the memory which is out of scope

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using CLion 2021.2.1 and I get these kind of 'warnings' here:

> ('The address of the local variable may escape the function'.
> 'Local variable 'testingStr' may point to the memory which is out of scope.')

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) **std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::operator[]** indeed '*Returns a **reference** to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.*'

But does it really matter actually? Don't `anotherStr` and `testingStr` both contain a copy of their respective unordered map's key's values (since the addresses of the strings and their respective unordered map's key's values seem to be different)?

Comment: Those warnings do not seem accurate. What compiler, or IDE feature like IntelliSense, are they from?

Comment: These come from CLion 2021.2.1.

Comment: Compiles clean for me clang/c++/msvc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/afndKc7e5

Comment: @ErnieSanderson *"These come from CLion 2021.2.1."* -- CLion is an IDE. Do you mean that it is the editor (not the compiler) that is warning you about this? Your compiler has the final word. If these are mere editor warnings, try compiling in spite of them.

Comment: The static analysis in your IDE has at least one bug.

Comment: Those warnings are not applicable to the code shown. If you are actually seeing these warnings, you probably tried to make a [MCVE] and accidentally removed the cause of the warning in the process. No pointer or reference to local variables escape the functions you have shown.

Comment: @JaMiT -- Yes, this is CLion's static code analysis in action, which is supposed to detect anomalous code before its compilation but ostensibly, as _molbdnilo_ pointed out, it didn't quite work in this case.

Comment: @ErnieSanderson I am not aware of an IDE that has code analysis that is 100% accurate. When you disagree with the judgement of your IDE, appeal to your compiler. ;)

Comment: There is no 100% accurate static analysis tool. Don't trust any of them, [*especially* the one in your compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/4T8Pcj9ax).